# Question About Transfer Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning

I want to calculate the costs of air pollution for a country, and I do not have a dependent variable, ie output values, in my dataset for that country. At this point, what techniques can I estimate the cost values?

As a method, is it possible to train the artificial neural networks with the data set of other countries and then make a forecast for the country without data with the transfer learning?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can train a neural network involving the data of all the countries, including the dependent variable as a 'target output'. Then, you use the trained neural network to predict the output for that country you mentioned.

It will work if your variables are good enough, i.e., if the output you are predicting is well described by (and correlated with) your input variables, so **make sure you are harvesting and using the correct features**.